# Ajax post has previous data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is driving me crazy. I know I am doing something wrong but what? The problem is I am getting previous data in my ajax call when I post it to php.

Story:  I click upload button which calls JavaScript loadme() where i am cleaning the input type file element. I then select file/files and click upload which calls doit() which internally calls uploadFiles(). UploadFiles makes an array with loaded images and post it to the php file through ajax.

I have tried plain javascript and jquery to clean file input element and php to set post values to null after using it, but still i am getting the previous values.

The form

```
<form id="theform" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="multifile">
   <input type="hidden" id="folderpath" name="folderpath" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($path)?>">
   <input name="upfiles[]" id="upfiles" type="file" multiple="" />
</form>
```

Javascript

```
async function doit(){
  //some code
  uploadFiles();
}

function loadmeup(){
  $('upfiles').value = '';    
  $('uploadbox').show();
}

function closeupload(){
  $('uploadbox').hide();
}

var masterFileArray = [];
var left_loaded_count = 0;
var progress = 0;

function uploadFiles() {
  var files = document.getElementById("upfiles").files;
  var path = document.getElementById('folderpath').value;
  var numOfFiles = files.length;
  alert(numOfFiles);

  if (files && numOfFiles>0) {
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        if(checkExtension(f.name) && checkSize(f.size)){
            progress = i+1/numOfFiles;
            var r = new FileReader();
            r.onload = (function (f) {
                return function (e) {
                    var contents = e.target.result;
                    masterFileArray.push({name:f.name, contents: contents, type:f.type, size:f.size}); 
                    console.log(f.name);
                    left_loaded_count -= 1;
                    if(left_loaded_count == 0)
                    {
                        var filesarray = null;
                        filesarray = JSON.stringify(masterFileArray);
                        console.log("after stringify: "+filesarray.length);
                        new Ajax.Request('upload_do.php', {
                            method: 'post',
                            parameters: {files: filesarray, folderpath:path},
                            onSuccess: function(transport){
                                var response = transport.responseText;
                                parent.notify(response);
                                closeupload();
                                get_listview(currlist,sort);                                    
                            }
                        });
                    }
                };
            })(f);
            left_loaded_count += 1;
            r.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
        else{
            alert('Invalid file extension or size ' + f.name);
            if(progress==0)
                location.reload();
        }
    }
  } else {
    alert('Failed to load files');
    closeupload();
  }
}
```

PHP

```
try{
  $error = null;
  $files = json_decode($_POST['files'],true);
  $numFiles = 0;
  foreach($files as $file){
    $output = $reso->writeUpload($file['contents'], $file['name']);
    $numFiles++;
  }
}
catch (Exception $ex){
  $error = $ex->getMessage();
  $GLOBALS['log']->log($error);
}
isset($_POST['files'])? $_POST['files'] = null: '';
if (!is_null($error))
  echo _($error);
else
  echo _($numFiles.' file'.(($numFiles > 1) ? 's' : '').' successfully 
uploaded');
```

Comment: what do you mean by "the previous values", exactly? Previous from when? It's not clear. And which requests are affected? Your code will try to make multiple requests, obviously. Since you trigger them in a loop, and ajax is async, they won't necessarily be executed and completed in the order you triggered them - could that be causing the symptoms?

Comment: No actually, in order to get a better control over the asynchronization of ajax  i implemented the logic of left_loaded_count it will trigger  the ajax call only one when all the images are done with loading and pushed into masterFileArray. By previous values, i mean if i upload one image after anohter, i get the first image as well along with the second one. Two different request but the second request will have the values from the first request as well.

Comment: You mean if you execute "uploadFiles()" more than once, you have this problem? For that you just need to put `masterFileArray = [];` inside the start of uploadFiles() method, on the first line of it, to reset the master array each time. Right now, you don't clear that array in between calls to uploadFiles, hence why you get previous results. You should probably reset `left_loaded_count` and `progress` as well, to be certain.